# The existence of a sub-open set $V$ of an open set $U$ in $R^n$ such that $V$ contains a compact set $K$.

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Suppose that an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfy $K \subset U$. Show that there exists an open set $V$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which satisfies all of the following conditions:
$$K \subset V, \text{Cl}(V) \subset U, \text{Cl}(V) \ \text{is} \ \text{compact}.$$
$\text{Cl}(V)$ denotes the closure of $V$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is a topological space problem.
I know intuitively that it is correct, but I cannot figure out how to describe it mathematically rigorously.
Here is what I have come up with:

Since $\text{Bd}(K)\cup\text{Bd}(U)=\emptyset$, we can take the $\epsilon$ such that
$$\epsilon=\inf\{d(u, k)\mid u\in \text{Bd(U)}, k\in \text{Bd(K)}\}$$
and let
$$V=K\cup\{B(k, \frac{\epsilon}{2})\mid k\in\text{Bd(K)}\}$$
Then this $V$ would satisfy the given conditions, which I failed to prove.

I would appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should move the last paragraph (the statement of the question) to the beginning of the post.

Comment: As you pointed out, I brought the problem statement first. Thank you.

Comment: I think you exchanged union and intersection in your post.

Comment: I made a mistake with cap and cup. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: You're guess is right. First of all, why $\epsilon >0$? What problem you found verifing the properties you need on V?

Comment: First, $\text{Bd}(K)\cap \text{Bd}(U)=\emptyset$. (If not, there exsits $a \in \text{Bd}(K)\cap\text{Bd}(U)$, such that $a \in \text{Bd}(K)\subset K$ and $a \in \text{Bd}(U)$. Since $U\cap\text{Bd}(U)=\emptyset$($\because\text{U is an open set}$), $K\not\subset U$, which is a contradiction. ) And so there exists a positive $\epsilon$, I thought.

I could not prove well that this V satisfies the third condition(I mean, it seems clear in $R^n$ that the closure of an open set $V$ is compact, but how do I write it?).

Comment: The proof that the boundaries are disjoint is good but is not enough: indeed  you could have the hyperbola $xy=1$ and the $x$ axis, which are disjoint, but for them there is no such positive $\epsilon$. Here the key is that $K$ is compact, indeed the distance between two disjoint closed sets is always positive if at least one is compact (the easy case is when are both compact, then you can derive the general case rom this one). Regarding compactness of $V$, a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff closed and bounded, so in general a closure of an open set is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of $V$ open with $K \subseteq V \subseteq \overline{V} \subseteq U$ easily follows from $\Bbb R^n$ being Hausdorff and locally compact. In a general space already.

No need for a metric or Euclidean specific argument.